# What is District 13?

Tags: movie, the-hunger-games, mockingjay

I haven't read the books. I had hoped that *Mockingjay: Part 1* would be sufficient to fill me in on the details presented in the books, as the previously two films had done.

So what exactly is District 13?  Each district seems to have a particular purpose for the Capitol, like District 12 for coal mining and other districts for forestry and agriculture, and so on. So did District 13 manufacture and supply weaponry to the Capitol? If not, how did they get their hands on such advanced weaponry?

Also, District 13 is built underground. Is it built on the original site of District 13 after the Capitol bombed them or is it located in some discreet location?

Comment: This may have been me reading into things, but I always assumed that District 13's central area was built in what remained of [NORAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Aerospace_Defense_Command), [Cheyenne Mountain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheyenne_Mountain_nuclear_bunker), or the long-fabled secret city in Colorado.

Comment: District 13 is a ghetto of Paris. Unable to control the crime in the area, authorities construct a wall around the suburb and leave it to rot. Wait, that's [somthing else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banlieue_13).

Comment: @phantom42 I heard similarly that it could be the [Raven Rock Mountain Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raven_Rock_Mountain_Complex).

Comment: District 13 resides on the east coast of the former United States.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**District 13 was the the nuclear industry.**

In *Catching Fire*, Katniss meets some refugees who are hoping to find sanctuary in District 13. They describe it thusly:

> “We think the people moved underground when everything on the surface was destroyed. We think they’ve managed to survive. And we think the Capitol leaves them alone because, before the Dark Days, District Thirteen’s principal industry was nuclear development.”
>
> “They were graphite miners,” I [Katniss] say. But then I hesitate, because that’s information I got from the Capitol.

I don’t recall if it’s ever explained whether they actually did graphite mining on the side, or if this was merely a Capitol front.

As Katniss flies towards District 13 in *Mockingjay*, we get some more detail:

> In the seventy-five years since the Dark Days—when 13 was said to have been obliterated in the war between the Capitol and the districts—almost all new construction has been beneath the earth’s surface. **There was already a substantial underground facility here**, developed over centuries to be either a clandestine refuge for government leaders in time of war or a last resort for humanity if life above became unlivable. Most important for the people of 13, **it was the center of the Capitol’s nuclear weapons development program**. During the Dark Days, the rebels in 13 wrested control from the government forces, trained their nuclear missiles on the Capitol, and then struck a bargain: They would play dead in exchange for being left alone. The Capitol had another nuclear arsenal out west, but it couldn’t attack 13 without certain retaliation. It was forced to accept 13’s deal. The Capitol demolished the visible remains of the district and cut off all access from the outside.

I think that answers all the questions in your post: it was a preexisting underground infrastructure, not an entirely new build, and it was in the same place as the original 13.

It also gets brief lip service in the film, but not in as much detail. When Boggs (head of District 13 security) takes Katniss to meet President Coin, they have this conversation in the lift/elevator:

> K: We were always told there was nothing left of 13.
>
> B: Capitol bombed the surface to rubble. But we’re military, so we learned to survive down here. Preparing, training. The war never stopped for us.

Comment: I think there may have been brief mention of this in the film, when Katniss is walking through 13's arsenal, but I don't have a copy of the film or script to hand.

Comment: The movie makes it seem like conventional, not nuclear, weapons.

Comment: It's reasonable to assume that they would have also done graphite mining for real. After 13 fell, the Capitol made District 2 their weapon makers, and they also did something real as a front (i forget what).

Comment: @Scimonster It’s quite possible, I just don’t think it’s confirmed. District 2’s front is stone mining, and the Capitol arsenal is in a mountain that used to be a stone mine.

Comment: Yup, that pretty much answers it. I wonder why Capitol was naive enough to believe such a situation wouldn't arise(District 13 starting a rebellion). They could have placed more of the Capitol security in such a sensitive District.

Comment: Graphite mining would fit perfectly well with being the nuclear industry, because graphite is used as a moderator in nuclear reactors.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the purpose of [District 13](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/District_13) was to produce weapons.
Especially nuclear weapons. This is the reason why the Capitol is quite afraid of District 13 and never tried to retake it.

I don't remember if it was mentioned anywhere if District 13 was underground from the beginning. But as they produced nuclear weapons it is very likely.